# How to move WooCommerce checkout errors/notices to another location in the checkout template file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have modified the WooCommerce template `form-checkout.php` and added some extra html elements like a wrapper inside the form element. However it looks like error messages are not added via any of the checkout template hooks but instead added as the first element inside the checkout form by Javascript. Because of this, the error messages appear outside my wrapper and breaks my layout.

I wan't to move this element:

[image]

Inside `woocommerce-checkout__main`:

[image]

I haven't been able to locate where the error messages are generated, but maybe there is some kind of filter to work with?